# Proof of summation of Stirling's Numbers of the first kind

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing, stirling-numbers

"Stirling's number of the first kind $s(n,k)$ is the number of permutations of ${1,2,...,n}$ with $k$-cycles. Prove that $n! =  \sum s(n,k)$ (from k = 1 to $\infty$) "

After checking a the first few 'n' I have managed to convince myself this is the case. As I didn't know where else to try, I attempted induction, showing true for n = 2 (I thought starting at 1 may be a little too general.) Then assumed true for n = t. Trying to work through n = t + 1 I am beginning to feel that  induction in this method won't work, unless I can figure a method, in terms of n and k on summing up terms. Can someone let me know if I am on the right track, or if I am going about this proof in the wrong way, and thus a guide on where to go from there. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Use a combinatorial argument. How many permutations of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ are there altogether? Does every permutation have a unique cycle structure?

Comment: There would be n! permutations. I don't know how to take into account the various ways of splitting e.g. s(4,2) could be two cycles of 2, or a cycle of 3 and a cycle of 1.?

Comment: @Duncan: There are indeed $n!$ permutations of $[n]=\{1,\ldots,n\}$. It doesn’t matter that $s(n,2)$ counts both permutations with cycle structure $(2,2)$ and permutations with cycle structure $(3,1)$; the point is that it counts all permutations of $[n]$ with exactly two cycles, and each permutation of $[n]$ has a unique cycle structure, so it doesn’t get counted in $s(n,k)$ for two different values of $k$.

Comment: It seems to me in this case that the proof is almost trivial then..?

Comment: @Duncan: Yes, it is, provided that you’ve already shown that each permutation has a unique cycle structure.

Comment: That's great thanks for your help Brian.

Comment: @Duncan: You’re welcome.